# django weird url reaction

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

i am having this weird url reaction.

this is my views.py

```
def user_edit(request):
  user = User.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))
  return render_to_response("editprofile.html",{'user':user},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is my form.

```
<form action="/update_userprofile/?userid={{user.id}}" ...
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'^update_userprofile/','home.views.update_userprofile')
```

but once i send the form, i am getting error:

```
 Internal Server Error: /update_userprofile/on
```

where is that `on` coming from? i dont understand what happens here.

thanks a lot .

Comment: this is main urlconf, @catherine

Comment: i am actually getting the right user with userid, but in the background i am getting 500 error saying the same error above. @catherine

Comment: do i have to escape the ? in the uri ? @catherine

Comment: Can you try setting Debug to True in settings.py?

Comment: @catherine, i am using both. because i have some data in the post and i have user id in the get. isnot it the reason??

Comment: @catherine, did you use both post and get? i mean, the form method is post and in action there is get url.

Comment: NO, I test them one by one

Comment: Don't ever use two methods in your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I try your codes. You did not put in your question what method did you use. So I try the GET and the output `User matching query does not exist`. I try the POST and it works now.

```
<form action="/update_userprofile/?userid={{user.id}}" method="POST">
```

Even though you have `user id` define in your url, you can still get the value from the method POST.

UPDATE:

You code is fine, just change the method into `method=POST` in your form

Comment: oh, so i can get userid in this way: 
``userid = request.POST.get('userid')`` ?

Comment: NO, your original codes is fine `userid = request.GET.get('userid')`, just change method in your form into `POST`

Comment: Remove the GET, use only POST

Comment: Also, the url to which you post should be changed, using the query string here isn't best practice. If you need the user id to be sent to the server do so by including it in a hidden field.

Comment: "If you need the user id to be sent to the server do so by including it in a hidden field" => or make it part of the url...